# YamlDotNet: How do I deserialize either a Sequence or a Mapping?

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

There's a YAML configuration file that my application loads:

```yaml
sonarr:
- base_url: abc1
  api_key: xyz1
- base_url: abc2
  api_key: xyz2
```

I want to change the schema for this to use a mapping (for named instances) rather than an array. Additionally, I want to continue to support array-style (with a deprecation message) for backward compatibility. So the `sonarr` content can either be a mapping or a sequence. The new schema would look like this:

```yaml
sonarr:
  instance1:
    base_url: abc1
    api_key: xyz1
  instance2:
    base_url: abc2
    api_key: xyz2
```

I've spent hours googling and trying different solutions. Nothing seems to work. The approach I was trying was something like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<T> LoadFromStream(TextReader stream, string configSection)
{
    var parser = new Parser(stream);
    parser.Consume<StreamStart>();
    parser.Consume<DocumentStart>();
    parser.Consume<MappingStart>();

    var validConfigs = new List<T>();
    while (parser.TryConsume<Scalar>(out var key))
    {
        if (key.Value != configSection)
        {
            parser.SkipThisAndNestedEvents();
            continue;
        }

        var evt = parser.Consume<NodeEvent>();
        var configs = evt switch
        {
            SequenceStart => _deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, T>>(parser)
                .Select(kvp =>
                {
                    kvp.Value.Name = kvp.Key;
                    return kvp.Value;
                })
                .ToList(),
            MappingStart => _deserializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(parser),
            _ => null
        };

        if (configs is not null)
        {
            ValidateConfigs(configSection, configs, validConfigs);
        }

        parser.SkipThisAndNestedEvents();
    }

    return validConfigs;
}
```

However, this won't work because the `Consume` and `TryConsume` methods eat the `MappingStart` / `SequenceStart` nodes, which makes it impossible to deserialize using List/Dictionary. I think to make this work I need a `Consume` that is more like a peek.

How should I go about handling this situation, or more generally, flexible schemas like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parser does has a [Peek](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/fd6731d4ab6bb4f3bec79a47b9ecb60f0d8e415f/YamlDotNet/Core/ParserExtensions.cs#L140) function, which is marked as obsolete, but has been replaced with an [Accept](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/fd6731d4ab6bb4f3bec79a47b9ecb60f0d8e415f/YamlDotNet/Core/ParserExtensions.cs#L89) function which does basically the same thing with an out parameter instead. However, the easiest thing to do would be to just switch on `parser.Current`:

```
configs = parser.Current switch
{
    MappingStart  => serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, T>>(parser)
                        .Select(kvp =>
                        {
                            kvp.Value.Name = kvp.Key;
                            return kvp.Value;
                        }),
    SequenceStart => serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(parser),
    _             => null
};
```

Make sure to drop the `parser.Consume` call before this.